I looked up to see a man standing over us
This is from a story about some children in a supermarket while their mum is in a rush.
.... after a while, we got so fed up, we went off to do our own shopping. We were just beginning to enjoy ourselves when suddenly we crashed into some trolleys. I looked up to see a man standing over us.
(The main said): And where is your mother?
The part "I looked up to see a man standing over us." caught my attention, because he didn't look up with an aim to see a man. He just looked up and then he saw a man.
We learnt at school that you use "to" tell about your purpose. You do something (to/in order to) do something else". For instance;

I bought a ticket to get on the bus.
I painted the wall to make it look good.
I like stars, so I looked up to see them at night.

But in the sentence I looked up to see a man standing over us., there is no purpose of seeing a man, but rather a coincidence or just a sequence of events. It actually means, "I looked up AND I saw a man....".
Since there is no "intention/purpose" relation between the two verbs, why do you think "to" is used here?

It's a result infinitive.

The infinitive of result:

The infinitive of result
A to-infinitive can be used to
express result; however, this use is more common in literary styles [don't necessarily agree with the literary idea but still...]:
Do you want to live to be a hundred?
She arrived home to receive a letter from her bank.

infinitive of result
I looked up to see a man standing over us. [the result is to see a man etc.]
to infinitive is not limited to purpose; it can also be a result.

Use of "to".
OP's query

The part "I looked up to see a man standing over us." caught my attention, because he didn't look up with an aim to see a man. He just looked up and then he saw a man

The preposition "to" has multiple meanings according to the dictionary. I want to draw your attention to this meaning
Ref. Cambridge dictionary

used after some verbs, especially when the action described in the infinitive will happen later:
She agreed to help.
I'll have to tell him.
Sadly, she didn't live to see her grandchildren.

In OP's sentence "to see a man" happened after looked up

Thanks for the answer, however, those examples don't apply, because "to" is followed by a noun in those examples (...to music, ....to applause, etc) , not  by another verb. In my question, "to" is followed by another verb.

@Yunus A better choice from Collins would have been farther down the page, in the section "Before the base form of a verb": "You use to before the base form of a verb when indicating what situation follows a particular action: From the garden you walk down to discover a large and beautiful lake." Or, as MW puts it, a bit harder to understand but more precise: "used as a function word to indicate purpose, intention, tendency, result, or end" [i.e. result].

@Yunus I had looked for different meanings. A similar meaning was there in Cambridge dictionary with verbs. The infinitive "to see happened after the narrator looked up. Edited
